# Where ruby versions should go in rbenv?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

I'm on ubuntu and installed rbenv + ruby-build. when I try to install any version I get an error. from the log it seems that it tries to install ruby at `/usr/local/rbenv/versions` which gives a `Permission denied` error. I'm not sure if this the right path versions should go? On my Mac its `/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/shims/ruby`!

Any clue?

Comment: How did you install rbenv? By default, it should be installed at ~/.rbenv, not /usr/local.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo <your_install_command>`.